# php - extract a 1-dimension array out of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an array as below and I want to get all the values in front of 'id', in a seperated array. Like: arry('12', '10', '11', '9')

```
 array
      3 => 
        array
          'occurance' => int 4
          'id' => string '12' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array
          'occurance' => int 3
          'id' => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array
          'occurance' => int 2
          'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      0 => 
        array
          'occurance' => int 1
          'id' => string '9' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$values = array(
        3 => array('occurance' => 4,'id' => '12'),
        1 => array('occurance' => 3,'id' => '10'),
        2 => array('occurance' => 2,'id' => '11'),
        0 => array('occurance' => 1,'id' => '9'));

$values = array_map(function($var){ return $var['id']; }, $values);
var_dump($values);
```

Output

```
array
  3 => string '12' (length=2)
  1 => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => string '11' (length=2)
  0 => string '9' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreach loop and put `id` in another array:

```
$newArray = array()
foreach($array as $val){
    $newArray[] = $val['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($YourArray as $ar)
{
    $FinalArray[] = $ar['id'];
}

print_r($FinalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 5.5 you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$idArray = array_column($multiArray, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
if(array_key_exists('id',$value))
$arr2[]=$value['id'];
}
```